# Cannot build Nvidia on kernel 5.0.0-32-generic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia

I'm trying to fix the dual monitor problem by installing Nvidia driver. The monitors were working perfectly before the last update. I tried to install Nvidia-435 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I get this error

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic (x86_64)
```

I checked the log file `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/435.21/build/make.log` for more information. I found the following lines in `make.log` file:

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";   
include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";
```

`autoconf.h` and `auto.conf` files are at the same location. Also, I couldn't find any `Makefile` where I can run `make oldconfig`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I thought Dynamic Kernel Module Support (DKMS) was used to build the Nvidia gear on kernel updates. Arch Linux has a pretty good page at [Dynamic Kernel Module Support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support). Here are my notes on keeping DKMS tidy on Ubuntu 18: [DKMS cleanup](https://pastebin.com/JnAg72Va). It cleans old modules. I don't have a recipe to rebuild an existing kernel module because I have not had to do it.